# Select Earliest Date Under Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written the script below and want to output the earliest date only where there are multiple entries for activity_value. What do I need to do to my script to achieve this please?

```
SELECT
cl.contact_number as contact_number,
c.label_name as label_name,
cc.activity_value as activity_value,
cc.activity as activity,

enquiry_source=case 
WHEN cc.activity_value in ('P','C','E','A','I')AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then s.source_desc
else NULL
end,

enquiry_date=case 
WHEN cc.activity_value = 'E' AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then cc.valid_from else NULL
end,

days_to_intender=case 
WHEN cc.activity_value = 'I' AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then cc.valid_from else NULL
end,

intender_date=case 
WHEN cc.activity_value = 'I' AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then cc.valid_from else NULL
end,

days_to_pledge=case 
WHEN cc.activity_value = 'P' AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then cc.valid_from else NULL
end,

pledge_date=case 
WHEN cc.activity_value = 'P' AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then cc.valid_from else NULL
end

FROM
contact_legacies cl

INNER JOIN contacts c ON cl.contact_number = c.contact_number
INNER JOIN contact_categories cc on cl.contact_number = cc.contact_number
INNER JOIN sources s on cl.source =s.source

WHERE
cc.activity_value in ('P','C','E','A','I')AND
cc.activity = 'LEGACY'

GROUP BY
cl.contact_number,c.label_name,cc.activity_value,cc.activity,s.source_desc,cc.valid_from

ORDER BY
cl.contact_number,c.label_name,cc.activity_value,cc.activity,s.source_desc,cc.valid_from
```

Example:

the case statements days_to_pledge and pledge_date are outputting two rows as follows. How do I get them to output only the earliest dates, as they both have an activity_value of P?

```
label_name  activity_value       days_to_pledge            pledge_date
Ms D Lom    P                2007-10-10 00:00:00.000       2007-10-10 00:00:00.000
Ms D Lom    P                2010-02-11 00:00:00.000       2010-02-11 00:00:00.000
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE...

I have just realised that the activity_value column can contain a combination of values not just 'P'. I think what I am aiming for is to output the earliest cc.valid_from date where there is more than one activity_value.

So for the output below the only result I want to see is the line with the activity value of I as it has the ealiest date of all of the entries displayed in intender_date.

[image: Output]

Comment: Take the cc.valid_from away from the group by and use the MIN aggregation on it (if there are no overlapping period, otherwise there are other ways)

Answer (score 0):

The following query uses logic along the lines of Serpiton's comment. Find the minimum pledge dates for each activity value, and then join to list only the rows with these pledge dates:

**EDIT**:

The query has been modified to remove `activity_value` in the inline view to fetch the earliest date among all `activity_value`'s.

```
SELECT
cl.contact_number as contact_number,
c.label_name as label_name,
cc.activity_value as activity_value,
cc.activity as activity,

enquiry_source=case 
WHEN cc.activity_value in ('P','C','E','A','I')AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then s.source_desc
else NULL
end,

enquiry_date=case 
WHEN cc.activity_value = 'E' AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then cc.valid_from else NULL
end,

days_to_intender=case 
WHEN cc.activity_value = 'I' AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then cc.valid_from else NULL
end,

intender_date=case 
WHEN cc.activity_value = 'I' AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then cc.valid_from else NULL
end,

days_to_pledge=case 
WHEN cc.activity_value = 'P' AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then cc.valid_from else NULL
end,

min_pledge_dates.pledge_date AS pledge_date

FROM
contact_legacies cl

INNER JOIN contacts c ON cl.contact_number = c.contact_number
INNER JOIN contact_categories cc on cl.contact_number = cc.contact_number
inner join sources s on cl.source =s.source
inner join
(select
-- cc.activity_value as activity_value, 
min(case when cc.activity_value = 'P' and cc.activity = 'LEGACY' then cc.valid_from else null
end) pledge_date
FROM
contact_legacies cl
INNER JOIN contacts c ON cl.contact_number = c.contact_number
INNER JOIN contact_categories cc on cl.contact_number = cc.contact_number
INNER JOIN sources s on cl.source =s.source
WHERE
cc.activity_value IN ('P','C','E','A','I')
AND cc.activity = 'LEGACY'
-- GROUP BY cc.activity_value
) min_pledge_dates
ON --cc.activity_value = min_pledge_dates.activity_value AND 
cc.valid_from = min_pledge_dates.pledge_date
WHERE
cc.activity_value in ('P','C','E','A','I')AND
cc.activity = 'LEGACY'

GROUP BY
cl.contact_number,c.label_name,cc.activity_value,cc.activity,s.source_desc

order by
cl.contact_number,c.label_name,cc.activity_value,cc.activity,s.source_desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have had a look and this seems to work however I have just realised that the activity_value column can contain a combination of values not just 'P'. I think what I am aiming for is to output the earliest cc.valid_from date where there is more than one activity_value.

Comment: You're welcome! Could you please publish more data and point out which value you expect in the result?

Comment: @MartinB I have modified the query to fetach the data for the earliest data. Please see the modified query above.